# Saving My Places with Google Maps SDK on iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I recently got invited to use Google's Map SDK/API's for iOS.  I've been reading through the limited docs that they have and I didn't see a way to access My Places.  Does anyone know of a way to access/save My Places on iOS?

Comment: In the meantime if you really want to see this implemented I would suggest adding it as an FR on https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?q=label:ApiType-IosSDK
And starting it, this way you will get an update if/when this is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find anything in the frameworks headers so i guess you need to use the Places API on your server and download the result for this.